# SpringBoot2 OAuth2 AuthorizationServer's Login Page is shown infinitely loop after login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm implemention OAuth2 System with Spring Boot 2.1.4 and Spring Security OAuth2.

I want to separate All Components `Client`, `ResourceServer`, `AuthorizationServer`)

so i create 3 projects each git repository.

in `Client`, I requested protected URL.

and Spring Security redirected me to Authorization Server's `/oauth/authorize`, and i redirected to Authorization Server's login page.

i tried login, and success.
and i redirected to my `Client` and redirected again to `AuthorizationServer`'s login page agian. (infinitely loop)

following is my 3 Components(`Client`, `AuthorizationServer`, `ResourceServer`)' Configuration.

**Client**

- gradle

```
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
    }

    ...

    dependencies {
    ...  


    /** Spring Security **/
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-client
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
    }
```

- application.yml

```
    ...

    spring:
        security:
            oauth2:
                client:
                    provider:
                        teemo:
                            authorizationUri: http://localhost:8082/oauth/authorize
                            tokenUri: http://localhost:8082/oauth/token
                            userInfoUri: http://localhost:8081/me


                    registration:
                        teemo:
                            clientId: foo
                            clientSecret: bar
                            provider: teemo
                            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
                            redirectUri: http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/teemo

    ...
```

- `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterImpl extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/error", "/webjars/**", "/resources/**", "/login**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Login();
    }

}
```

**AuthorizationServer**

- gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

...

dependencies {
    ...

    /** Spring Security **/
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'

    ...
}
```

- application.yml

```
    spring:
        security:
            user:
                name: user
                password: user
    ...
```

- `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` config

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterImpl extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/token", "/login**").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

- `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` config

```java
@Component
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapterImpl extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapterImpl(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("foo")
                .secret("bar")
                //.authorities("USER")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit", "refresh_token")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/teemo")
                .scopes("read");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
            }
}
```

**ResourceServer**

- gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

...
dependencies {
    ...

    /** Spring Security **/
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-resource-server
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-resource-server', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
}
```

- application.yml

```
...
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:8082/oauth/check_token
```

- `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfigurerAdapterImpl extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/me").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:8082/oauth/check_token");
        tokenService.setClientId("foo");
        tokenService.setClientSecret("bar");
        return tokenService;
    }
}
```

and following is screenshot for infinitely looping after login.

[infinitely image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85qzy.jpg)

how can i fix this?  and i'm spring boot & security newbie.

Comment: Can you post the project on Github?

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** code example. It is very hard to read all this code. This process of minifying your code could also help to find the problem by yourself. In this minimal example specify where exactly the error occurs and what you expect. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EugenCovaci of course.
[OAuth2Client](https://github.com/teemodevs/MainWebApplication)
[OAuth2AuthorizationServer](https://github.com/teemodevs/OAuth2AuthorizationServer)
[OAuth2ResourceServer](https://github.com/teemodevs/OAuth2ResourceServer)

thanks !

Comment: @UliSotschok  Sorry for my low quality question.
im spring boot & security beginner so i dont know where is wrong point.

i will try to minimize this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. Among them:

1. **You need to have a specific context path for each project** (because the session tracking is cookie based and each session cookie must have a unique path)
2. There is no `/me` path mapping on resource server
3. The `redirectUri` should have the format `<client_url>/login/oauth2/code/<provider_name>`

I have made a pull request for each or your projects that fixed the issues.

For an example of OAUTH2 with String Boot take a look [here](https://github.com/ecovaci/oauth2example)

If you find something unclear with the modifications I have made, feel free to ask me.

Comment: you saved my developer life. thanks.  thanks very much.

this working perfectly as i intended.

thank you ! Eugen Covaci !

:D